# Cannot assign to read only property in React.js

Tags: javascript, react-redux

```
    const { draggedFrom } = dragAndDrop;
    const fromIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.Sort === draggedFrom);
    const toIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.Sort === sort);
    const newList = list.slice();
    newList[fromIndex].Sort = sort; => bug
    newList[toIndex].Sort = draggedFrom;
```

My array:

```
const items = [
  {
    Domain: '33i.com',
    Sort: 3,
  },
  {
    Domain: 'one.com',
    Sort: 1,
  },
  {
    Domain: 'two.com',
    Sort: 2,
  },
];
```

I am trying to modify the value of an object in an array.
But it throws error : [image]

I googled but cannot find people who write code like mine.
Is there anything I am missing?

I am sorry. I found that my value is got from useSelector, that might be some trick in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a `const` when the value is set it can't be modified.  use `let` or `var` instead to modify the value.

[const doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

**From site:**

> The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it
> can't be redeclared.

Comment: The usage of `const` is not the problem here. As you said, a constant can't be reassigned or redeclared, but if that constant is an array or an object you can actually update or remove items or properties.

Comment: `const array = [1]                                                        
array[0] = 2 // OK                                                         
array = [3] // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.           `

This happens because the constant stores a reference to the array, not the actual array.